# how do I fix this c++ typelist template compile error?

Tags: c++, templates, typelist

(from reading chapter 3 of modern c++ design)

typelist.hpp:

```
class NullType {};

struct EmptyType {};


template <class T, class U>
struct Typelist
{
  typedef T Head;
  typedef U Tail;
};

#define TYPELIST_1(T1) Typelist<T1, NullType>
#define TYPELIST_2(T1, T2) Typelist<T1, TYPELIST_1(T2) >
#define TYPELIST_3(T1, T2, T3) Typelist<T1, TYPELIST_2(T2, T3) >
#define TYPELIST_4(T1, T2, T3, T4) Typelist<T1, TYPELIST_3(T2, T3, T4) >
#define TYPELIST_5(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5) Typelist<T1, TYPELIST_4(T2, T3, T4, T5) >
#define TYPELIST_6(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6) Typelist<T1, TYPELIST_5(T2, T3, T4, T5, T6) >


namespace TL
{
  template <class TList> struct Length;
  template <> struct Length<NullType>
  {
    enum { value = 0 };
  };

  template <class T, class U>
    struct Length< Typelist<T, U> >
    {
      enum { value = 1 + Length<U>::value };
    };


  template <class Head, class Tail>
    struct TypeAt<Typelist<Head, Tail>, 0>
    {
      typedef Head Result;
    };

  template <class Head, class Tail, unsigned int i>
    struct TypeAt<Typelist<Head, Tail>, i>
    {
      typedef typename TypeAt<Tail, i-1>::Result Result;
    };

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "typelist.hpp"

Typelist<int, double> foo;

int main() {
}
```

g++ main.cpp

```
typelist.hpp:37: error: ‘TypeAt’ is not a template
typelist.hpp:43: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class Head, class Tail> struct TL::TypeAt’
typelist.hpp:43: error:   expected a type, got ‘i’
```

Why do I get this error? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a forward declaration.

This is a partial specialization:

```
template <class Head, class Tail>
struct TypeAt<Typelist<Head, Tail>, 0>
```

But the compiler has no idea what it's a specialization of. Add this before it:

```
template <class List, unsigned Index>
struct TypeAt;
```

This let's the compiler know: "There is a class `TypeAt` which has two template parameters." So now when you specialize it, the compiler knows what class you're talking about.

---

Note, your usage of `Typelist` is incorrect. These algorithm's are *sentinel-terminated*. This means, like C-strings, they expect the data to be concluded with a special value. In our case, this is `NullType`.

So, take [Éric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150618/how-do-i-fix-this-c-typelist-template-compile-error/2150669#2150669)'s advice. (i.e. hint: if you found his answer helpful, up-vote it.)

Answer (score 1):

Typelist is designed to be used recursively: It expects its second templater parameter to be either another Typelist, or NullType (signaling the end of recursion).

To define foo, you should write:

```
TYPELIST_2(int, double) foo;
```

or, if you want to avoid macros:

```
Typelist<int, Typelist<double, NullType> > foo;
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, nor a problem.

Comment: @GMan: Re-reading the compiler error reported in the question, I agree that this is not *the* problem. However, it is *a* problem: TL::Lenght or TL::TypeAt can't be used on a Typelist as defined in the question.

Comment: @Eric: You are very right about it being a problem, my mistake. :)