# type visitor over typelist in c++

Tags: c++, templates, typelist

I'm looking for a way to implement 'type' visitor over c++ typelist. Here, I meant type visitor as to execute particular operator (such as sizeof) over types in typelist.

Conceptually what I want to do is:

```
typedef TYPELIST_3(bool, int, double) tl;
size_t tl_size     = TL_sum_size<tl>();  // 13 = 1+4+8
size_t tl_min_size = TL_min_size<tl>();  // 1
size_t tl_max_size = TL_max_size<tl>();  // 8
vector<size_t> tl_sizes = TL_list_size<tl>();  // {1, 4, 8}
TL_AddCounter<tl>(3); // Call AddCounter(3) for each type in typelist
```

Of course, each function should be templetized over typelist. 
The example uses sizeof, and `static void T::addCounter(int x)` in the typelist (to track how many time that type is used).
Generically, I want to execute any arbitrary 'static' operation about type with arbitrary parameters.

Well, first of all, is any of functions above possible? if yes, how can I do? I am not sure how to iterate through typelist.

Comment: [I used MaxSize and Length in my variant implementation based on typelist][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150892/how-to-build-this-c-typelist-into-a-variant/3552166#3552166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct SizeVisitor : std::integral_constant<unsigned int, sizeof(T)> { };

template <template <typename> class Visitor, typename ...Args> struct Visit;

template <template <typename> class Visitor, typename T, typename ...Rest>
struct Visit<Visitor, T, Rest...> : std::integral_constant<unsigned int,
    Visitor<T>::value + Vist<Visitor, Rest...>::value> { };

template <template <typename> class Visitor>
struct Visit<Visitor, T> : std::integral_constant<unsigned int, 0U> { };
```

Now you can say `Visit<SizeVisitor, double, char, int>::value`.

You can modify this approach to take a single (say `tuple`) class instead of the naked types for the type list, and you can also generalize the `SizeVisitor` into some arbitrary binary functor, akin to `std::accumulate` (and instead of `0u` you'd have the accumulator's neutral element).

Comment: Thanks for very fast answer. This certainly works for sum_size. I think this should work for similar cases.  However, does this work for static void T::AddCounter(int x)? Also, std::integral_constant is for c++11. Can I do same with c++03?

Comment: @xosp7tom: `integral_constant` is just a tiny class that has a `static const` integral member `value`; you can write this by hand in ten seconds, or just define a suitable `value` member. By the way, C++ **is** C++11 ;-) Also, all the variadic template stuff is C++11; you'll have to be seriously more cumbersome to write something similar in C++03.

Comment: @xosp7tom: It's very easy to write something that "calls something for each type"; just emulate the partial specialization and pack expansion. Everything can be done; let me know if you want details on a particular case.